# CCS Issue for Image Sizing - Woocommerce Store

Tags: css, wordpress, image, woocommerce

I'm trying to make all product images the same height. I feel like I should just be able to add the following to ".product-image":

height: 300px; 
width: auto; 
position: absolute;

but that doesn't work here.

Here is a link to the page with the issue:

http://www.hothothot.com/shop/product-category/enter-at-your-own-risk-10/

How can I make these images the same size? again, I think that they should be governed by .product-images, but the only thing that seems to work is when I change the more generic "img" for media=All which then messes up other images on the site.

Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Remove `height:auto;` in your code and if you want a specific `height` on it then use `height:50px;` or whatever you would like.

```
img{
    border-style:none;
    vertical-align:top; 
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto; // <--- Remove that
}
```

Online tools like picresize are great help in your case http://www.picresize.com/. You can resize the images so even with `height:auto;` it would work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference them via

```
.product-images img {
   // css here
}
```

There appears to be no class called `product-image`, so this references any image within the `a` tag with the class `product-images`.

However, increasing the height when all the images are different sizes and the outer tag has a max-width may well lead to some images being stretched and looking odd.

Stretching small images can also make them quite blocky.

If the idea is for a tidy alignment, you are probably better setting a height on the `.product-images` tag and making the images vertically align within it.

(Also, the simplest way to make them the same size may well be to edit the images and upload them the same size)

Answer (score 0):

The product-image class is on the link that surrounds the image. 
The image itself has two classes: attachment-shop_catalog and wp-post-image.
So, you could try something like this:

```
.attachment-shop_catalog .wp-post-image {
    height:300px;
}
```

The other issue is that the img has width and height specified in the html.

To make sure the image scales properly you should set the width to auto.
Try something like this:

```
.attachment-shop_catalog .wp-post-image {
    height:300px !important;
    width:auto !important;
}
```

I added !important so that it will override the hard coded html dimensions.

Hope this helps

Comment: For some reason apply CSS to .attachment-shop_catalog .wp-post-image .product-images doesn't work...any other suggestions?